I don't understand the syntax
I was watching a video on YouTube with subtitles (normal subtitles, not automatic ones).
So I've met a proposition whose syntax is not clear for me.
"Most infamously, though, were Epstein's targeted political connections."
What I don't understand is to what word  "infamously" is connected (in a sense that it's an adverb and it must be connected to some verb). Maybe I've understood something wrongly from the start.

It is an error - should be an adjective (infamous).

We'd need to see the sentence or two before that one to be sure, but it does look to be an error.

People speak like they speak. Speech results in oddities. Suggest you look up connected speech.

I add to what @Michael Harvey said.
There is a typographical mistake, and it should be

Most infamous, though, were Epstein's targeted political connections.

The sentence is of an inverse copular construction and
has similar meaning as this one in the more usual form SUBJECT + BE + SUBJECT COMP:
Epstein's targeted political connections were (the) most infamous.
The subject complement is the adjective phrase.

How do you know it's a typo? Do you have a nickname, by the way?

Thanks, @Lambie.  I can’t think of any words that could fit in this sentence and look close enough to infamously to have been autocorrected to this.  I don’t have a nickname.

I agree with the grammar correction but  it's just a slip.
